# How TO Get categories image in rest api magento 2?

Tags: php, rest, web-services, magento, magento2

I am Using this api URl "www.mydomain.com/rest/V1/categories" but can't show the categories image how to add image key in rest api  please help me.

Comment: Can you post some code what your are trying to accomplish?

Comment: did you get any solution for same ?

Comment: [Please edit your question and add further information in question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54395994/edit). Don't post it on answer section.  Also avoid post gibberish content.